# Am getting "451 4.7.1 Local configuration error, please try again later"

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, email, smtpclient

I am trying to send email with gmail smtp server and am getting this error even whe using different accounts to test

```
Dim myMail As New MailMessage
myMail.To.Add(New MailAddress("myemail@yahoo.com"))
myMail.Subject = "subject"
myMail.From = New MailAddress("fromemail@gmail.com")
myMail.Body = "the message"
Dim mySMTP As New SmtpClient()
mySMTP.Host ="smtp.google.com"
mySMTP.Port = 587
mySMTP.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
mySMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("musername@gmail.com", "mygmailpass")
mySMTP.EnableSsl = true
mySMTP.Timeout = 30000
mySMTP.Send(myMail)
```

An the error am getting

```
451 4.7.1 Local configuration error, please try again later
```

What causes this error. my username and password are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server you are talking to thinks it is not configured correctly.  Either there is no fault with your code per se (I haven't actually tried to review it; I'm not familiar with your platform) or -- this is a stretch -- your code happens to expose a bug in the mail server which causes it to give you a misleading error message.